# FlaskApp returning http 500 in apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to host my python 3.4 flask app through apache and mod_wsgi. Running the app through flasks own server works fine. The app was made in a virtual environment, pyvenv-3.4.

However, when trying to connect to the apache server in a browser, it throws a 500 http error. Configs and logs are attached. I think this has to do with using pyvenv and not virtualenv (from pip). 
Flask documentation tells me to activate the virtual environment using this line

```
activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'
```

however, that produces an IOError as the file does not exist. I tried pointing it to the 'activate'-file instead, and activate.csh, activate.fish, with no luck. All files produces SyntaxError on the deactivate-line.

How can I run this app through Apache with my virtualenv?

**flaskapp.wsgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
activate_this = '/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/bin/activate'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'some secret key'
```

**Apache VirtualHost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName example.org # my server name
            ServerAlias gallifrey 192.168.0.84
            ServerAdmin admin@example.org # my admin
            WSGIScriptAlias /flask /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
            <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            LogLevel warn
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Hierarchy**

```
/var/www/FlaskApp
  flaskapp.wsgi
  FlaskApp/
    bin/
      activate
      activate.csh
      activate.fish
      easy_install, easy_install-3.4
      pip, pip3, pip3.4
      python, python3, python3.4
    include/
    lib/
    scripts/
    static/
    templates/
    app.py
    __init__.py
```

Trying to open the webpage I get a http 500 error:

**Apache error.log**

```
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81] mod_wsgi (pid=31629): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81] mod_wsgi (pid=31629): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'.
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81]     execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/bin/activate", line 4
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81]     deactivate () {
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81]                   ^
[Fri May 02 10:22:58 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.81] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the virtualenv `activate` *shell* script in your Python WSGI file? That won't work. See https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments instead.

Comment: @Sklirg Could you please update answer with working config. I'm trying to replicate this setup and it's not working, still getting 500 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either follow the [VirtualEnvironments instructions](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments), or you can replicate what `virtualenv`'s `activate_this.py` script does:

```
import sys
import os

old_os_path = os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + os.pathsep + old_os_path
base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
else:
    site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
import site
site.addsitedir(site_packages)
sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
sys.prefix = base
# Move the added items to the front of the path:
new_sys_path = []
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

You could make this a more general function:

```
import sys
import os

def activate_venv(path):
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        bin_dir = os.path.join(path, 'Scripts')
        site_packages = os.path.join(base, 'Lib', 'site-packages')
    else:
        bin_dir = os.path.join(path, 'bin')
        site_packages = os.path.join(BASE, 'lib', 'python%s' % sys.version[:3], 'site-packages')
    os.environ['PATH'] = bin_dir + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
    prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
    import site
    site.addsitedir(site_packages)
    sys.prefix, sys.real_prefix = path, sys.prefix

    # Move the added items to the front of the path:
    new_sys_path = []
    for item in list(sys.path):
        if item not in prev_sys_path:
            new_sys_path.append(item)
            sys.path.remove(item)
    sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

Put that in a module on your default Python module search path, import `activate_venv` and pass in the result of `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`:

```
from somemodule import activate_venv
import os.path
activate_venv(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/FlaskApp
```

and just have mod_wsgi handle setting it up or you?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a Python virtual environment, with applications like Django or Flask you have to make sure Apache picks up the location of the WSGI path.

If you have a Debian distro and used the package manager to install Apache you should have a directory structure for the config files like this:
/etc/apache2/.

Edit a VirtualHost config file (e.g. AppName.conf) under "/etc/apache2/sites-available/AppName.conf" and follow the example below for a Flask app under Python v3.5:

```
WSGIPythonPath /<PATH_OF_PYTHON_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT>/lib/python3.5/site-packages
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <HOST or IP_ADDRESS>
        ServerAdmin your-email@domain.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/app_name/your_wsgi_app.wsgi
        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        <Directory /var/www/app_name/AppName/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/app_name/AppName/static
        <Directory /var/www/app_name/AppName/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # e.g. LogLevel debug
        LogLevel <info|warn|error|debug>
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should avoid using ``WSGIPythonPath`` to set up a Python virtual environment. You should also avoid embedded mode as you are using, use daemon mode instead as it is better. For virtual environment set up see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add this above and outside  in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and it worked.

```
WSGIPythonPath /your_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-package
```

Comment: When referring to Python virtual environment, the preferred way is using ``WSGIPythonHome``. You should only use ``WSGIPythonPath`` when referring to free standing directories unrelated to a Python installation.

Comment: I tried WSGIPythonHome but it did not work, i followed this site:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: What did you set ``WSGIPythonHome`` to? It should be the value that you get for ``sys.prefix`` in the Python interpreter. And if you were using mod_wsgi daemon mode, you should be using ``python-home`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` option anyway.

Comment: Here is my settings is httpd.conf
`WSGIPythonHome /home/kuthoong248/dnsrecordschecking/flaskapp/env`
`WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp python-path=/home/kuthoong248/dnsrecordschecking/flaskapp/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages user=kuthoong248 group=kuthoong248 threads=5`.

Comment: It raise a error: Unable to import 'site' module(I see a line import site in file activate_this.py). but when I active virtualenv and type python, then import site, it import ok. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: You would usually get that error when mod_wsgi was compiled for a different Python version that the virtual environment you are trying to use. How many Python versions do you have installed?

Comment: Two version: 2.6 and 2.7. I set up my virtualenv using python2.7

Comment: Make sure that your mod_wsgi isn't compiled for Python 2.6. Swap it with one built using mod_wsgi to make sure. To check what version mod_wsgi was compiled for see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use

Comment: I found out that mod_wsgi was complied with python2.6. Then I yum remove mod_wsgi, install mod_wsgi and mod_wsgi_httpd with pip, but it doesn't work, then i reinstall python2.7 with enable-shared, download source code mod_wsgi and recomplied with python2.7 followed this link [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/453977/configuring-mod-wsgi-to-use-python-2-7), LoadModule in httpd.conf. Then it worked. Thank you so much @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: You wouldn't have needed mod_wsgi_httpd package if system Apache already existed. Better to rely on system Apache.